# Simplest but bulletproof way do deduce timezone of a webpage using python (based on URL)?

Tags: python, django, timezone

I'm writing Django based RSS/Atom reader which is  Time Zone aware - and i consider it necessary. But some websites use TZ naive format (even the big ones - Hello The Guardian) what is the best way to deduce a proper timezone based on website?

Comment: If you are crawling the feeds periodically like once in X min, you can use your crawl time instead (time the news story first appeared on the feed). Not precise, but consistent.

Comment: I was thinking about using ‘python-geoip2‘ but I'm worried about a) it's an overkill - one more depencity b) not such reliable

Comment: Based on *what* from a website?  Your question is unclear.  Do you mean, given a URL what is the time zone?  That is nonsensical.

Comment: @Matt Johnson First-I thought it's obvious, second- didn't want do discourage other approaches or suggest anything. I got RSS/atom feed URL in my DB and that's my starting point.

Answer (score -1):

> what is the best way to deduce a proper timezone based on website?

You cannot deduce a time zone based on a web site.  A web site can be served from anywhere in the world, and contain content about anywhere in the world, or multiple different places.

> I got RSS/atom feed URL in my DB and that's my starting point.

You cannot tell anything from the URL alone.  You can however, assuming the URL points at a valid RSS or ATOM feed, fetch the content of the feed and examine the dates contained within.

- The [RSS specification](https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss2.html) defines a `pubDate` attribute on the `<item>` element, and an optional `lastBuildDate` on the `<channel>` element.  Both are in the [RFC 822 date format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-5).

  - This format may contain a time zone offset in the form `+/-HHMM`, or one of a handful of limited abbreviations, as defined in [section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-5).
- The [ATOM specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287) defines a `published` element on each `<entry>` element, and an `updated` attribute on the `<feed>` element.  Both are in the [RFC 3339 date format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339).

  - This format must contain a time zone offset in the form `+/-HH:MM`, or `Z` (for UTC).
  - Note that this format is a particular profile of [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

You can therefore extract the offset from the timestamp of a channel/feed or from individual messages.  However:

- There's no guarantee the time zone offset was set correctly to begin with.
- The source may or may not have normalized the data to UTC, in which case all offsets will be zero.
- An offset does not uniquely identify a time zone anyway.  See "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: I know all that. I'm using timezones from RSS/Atom where available. My question is about what can i do where there is no TZ info in the feed itself

Comment: It cannot be done. I explained why in the very first part of my answer.